# Search for a specific group in AD with a part of the CN name

Tags: c#, regex, directoryentry

In the AD, there is a list of groups such as:

- ServerDEV_4283V
- ServerDEV_4221C
- ServerDEV_9080M
- ServerDEV_2722W

....

I am able to get one specific group but I can't get a list of groups with starting with ServerDEV_4.

Here is my code block:

```
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://YourServer/OU=SubOU,OU=TopLevelOU,dc=test,dc=com", userName, password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

try
{     
     DirectoryEntry childGroup = entry.Children.Find("CN=ServerDEV-4283V");
     // create group here
}
catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException exception)
{
    // handle the "child not found" case here ...
}
```

Is there a way I could do the RegEx like "ServerDEV-4" so I can get 2 top groups?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the wildcard would be enough.

```
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://YourServer/OU=SubOU,OU=TopLevelOU,dc=test,dc=com", userName, password,AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

try
{     
     DirectoryEntry childGroup = entry.Children.Find("CN=ServerDEV-4*");
     // create group here
}
catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException exception)
{
    // handle the "child not found" case here ...
}
```